# How to locating similar HTML elements in Watir using Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am trying to click links on a page and able to do only the first one. There are four more having similar code, but it says it cannot locate the other four.

This is the line of code that works:

```
@browser.div(class:'ms-vb itx').link(:text =>'Rapid Alignment').click
```

This is one of the four that does not work:

```
@browser.div(class:'ms-vb itx').link(:text =>'Design Develop Integrate and Test').click
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="1" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/…; onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Rapid Alignment</a></div>

<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="3" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/…; onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Design Develop Integrate and Test</a></div>
```

Comment: It is not clear, can you describe more

Comment: So there are 5 links on a page. All 5 have similar source code. I am trying to click each one of them and able to do only the first one, even though I call the other 4 the same way. The first link is visible on the page as 'Rapid Alignment' and this code works to locate that link -@browser.div(class:'ms-vb itx').link(:text =>'Rapid Alignment').click. The second link is visible on the page as 'Design Develop Integrate and Test' and this code does not work to locate it -@browser.div(class:'ms-vb itx').link(:text =>'Design Develop Integrate and Test').click

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Silently fails?  Throws an `unable to locate element` error?  Without the associated HTML, it's just speculation.  Please edit the question and include the HTML.

Comment: Yes Throws an unable to locate element error

Comment: HTML of the first link that works <div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="1" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="https://asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7B498507E1%2D9E59%2D40CB%2D882F%2D29589F70D58E%7D&amp;ID=1&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100223D60E8C5C0184998F45999F450A3A5" onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Rapid Alignment</a></div>

Comment: HTML of the second link that does not get located <div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="3" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="https://asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7B498507E1%2D9E59%2D40CB%2D882F%2D29589F70D58E%7D&amp;ID=3&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100223D60E8C5C0184998F45999F450A3A5" onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Design Develop Integrate and Test</a></div>

Comment: @engineersmnky I have tried locating just the second one alone too. It does not locate it.

Comment: @Bhuvana Please read my answer below, all you need is link text, nothing else, your code fails because every time it looks into the first division.

Comment: @RAJ, thanks for your help, but just using link text, was not locating the element.

Comment: @Bhuvana It's because more than one link present and some of them were hidden so it tries to interact the first one so it gives you the error that it's not visible, I have updated my answer, you can try that one and let me know. I have included the visible locator now.

Comment: @Bhuvana See the updated answer with visible locators, you don't have to bother about the index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to specify which `<div>` you are targeting.  There are two or possibly more `<div>` tags with the same `class` attribute.

Given this HTML snippet:

```
<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="1" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/…" onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Rapid Alignment</a></div> 

<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx586" id="3" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0xb008031061" EventType=""><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="asdm.nwie.net/_layouts/15/…" onclick="EditLink2(this,586);return false;" target="_self">Design Develop Integrate and Test</a></div>
```

You need to target the appropriate `<div>` by supplying the index in the locator:

```
p b.div(:class => 'ms-vb itx').link(:text => 'Rapid Alignment').exists?
#=> true
p b.div(:class => 'ms-vb itx').link(:text => 'Design Develop Integrate and Test').exists?
#=> false
p b.div(:class => 'ms-vb itx', :index => 1).link(:text => 'Design Develop Integrate and Test').exists?
#=> true
```

But locating elements by index can be fragile if and when UI elements change.  You should consider locating using the `id` attributes, which--according to [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)--are unique.

Comment: This is completely unnecessary because link text itself is enough to identify the link.

Comment: "You should consider locating using the id attributes, which should be unique." IDs _must_ be unique according to the spec.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the use of `#div` which will return a single div

Try this instead

```
divs = @browser.divs(class:'ms-vb itx')
```

Then

```
divs.each do |d|
  d.link.click
end
```

`#divs` returns a `DivCollection` which includes `Enumerable` so all `Enumerable` methods will work as well including things like `select` e.g.

```
divs.select { |d| d.link(:text =>'Rapid Alignment') }
```

Comment: Your code will fail if any of the division doesn't have the link and your last code is not even an expected answer, she doesn't want to select a link which has the text of Rapid alignment, she wants to click all the link.

Comment: @RAJ this was an example of how to facilitate the question. the assumption is that `ms-vb itx` is a link wrapper and based on the HTML posted this appears to be the case. As for `select` it was an example on how to filter out the desired link from the `DivCollection`. P.S. your code will not work either (those in glass houses)

Answer (score 0):

This fails because div is same so it tries to locate the same div everytime and starts to search the given link, So it fails second time when you tries to locate the different link.

Actually you do not need of div to locate that link, you simply write this code it will work

```
b.link(:text=>'Rapid Alignment',:visible=>true).click

b.link(:text=>'Design Develop Integrate and Test',:visible=>true).click
```

That link text itself is the identification to that link, So you do not need of any division, directly write b.link(), it's enough.

Comment: without the index, it spit the error unable to locate the error. Thanks.

Comment: @Bhuvana you don't need any index as long as your link text is unique. simply try writing `b.a(:text,'Rapid Alignment').click` it will surely work.

Comment: @Raj, it is not working. Gives the error Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

Comment: @Bhuvana Okay, then more than one link present I guess, So you use this code `b.link(:text=>'Rapid Alignment',:visible=>true).click`

Comment: @RAJ if both were to be visible then you would be clicking the first one

Comment: @Raj, it resulted in TypeError: expected one of [String, Regexp], got true:TrueClass

Comment: @Bhuvana Did you use the colon before :visible ?

Comment: @engineersmnky no link text itself is the identification.

Comment: @Gopal there are 2 links with this text thus the error reported above. Plus one should never rely on the uniqueness of link text what if I had one in the navigation bar and one in the footer? As for your comment about visible it is expecting `"true"` not `true` [Source Reference](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/lib/watir/elements/select.rb#L120) in HTML `visible="true"` not `visible=true`

Comment: @engineersmnky please read here http://watir.github.io/watir-6-1/ I have posted code after execution, it works fine for me

Comment: @Bhuvana please read here to know how to use visible locators http://watir.github.io/watir-6-1/